# App-Maker How to Assign Roles to Users With Script (NO APP SETTINGS)?

Tags: google-app-maker

I am learning a bit about​ ​App Maker, and I have seen the​ ​`Application Settings -> Security`, which can be registered and assigned Roles to users.

How to do this with script when registering a new user in my app?

​​[image: Fields]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Maker doesn't provide a way add/remove roles or add/remove users(group) to/from role in runtime. Out of the box you can manage user permissions in deployment settings (design time):
https://developers.google.com/appmaker/security/secure-your-app#secure_deployments

However, you can associate App Maker Roles with User Groups and add remove members using Admin SDK [advanced service](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/settings#advanced_google_services):

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory#add_group_member

```javascript
// Server script
function addGroupMember_() {
  var userEmail = 'liz@example.com';
  var groupEmail = 'bookclub@example.com';
  var member = {
    email: userEmail,
    role: 'MEMBER'
  };
  member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
}
```

Be aware, that to run this code you'll need to [run your app on developer's behalf](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/security/secure-your-app#run_an_app_as_the_user_or_developer) (what has its pros and cons...).